# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed

Tags: django, csrf

When I click on ok button in add_tech.html then it will redirect me on upload_type.html.
But it show error while clicking on ok button.

ERROR -

> Forbidden (403)
>   CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>   Help
>   Reason given for failure:
>       CSRF token missing or incorrect.

My template(add_tech.html) -

```py
<form action="/uploads/type/" method="post">
  <label for="your_name">New Tech: </label>
  <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

My Template(upload_type.html)-

```py
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
</form>
```

My View.py -

```py
def upload_type(request):
    if request.method =='POST':   
        details = NameForm(request.POST) 
        if details.is_valid():
            return render(request, "core/upload_type.html", {'form':details})  
    else:
        details = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'core/upload_type.html', {'form': details})
```

My Url.py -

```py
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^uploads/type/$', views.upload_type, name='upload_type'),]
```

My form.py -

```py
from uploads.core.models import Name 
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Name
        fields = ('your_name', )
```

My Models.py-

```py
class Name(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the csrf token like this for your post method in the django template

```
 <form action="/uploads/type/" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="your_name">New Tech: </label>
  <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For POST request, csrf token is required. So in your template, add `{% csrf_token %}.

```html
<form action="/uploads/type/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="your_name">New Tech: </label>
  <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

From the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-template):

> Django ships with an easy-to-use protection against Cross Site Request
>   Forgeries. **When submitting a form via POST with CSRF protection
>   enabled you must use the csrf_token template** tag as in the preceding
>   example.